# Jenkins Conditional Step Check if ENV variable is set

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

How can I use the Conditional Step Jenkins plugin, to check if an environment variable is set? If it is set, proceed as normal. If it is not set, skip the post-build actions and mark build as a pass (not a failure).

Or if there is a way to do this without using the Conditional Step plugin, I would be open to that as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do this with the [Flexible Publish plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Flexible+Publish+Plugin). Under Conditional action select **Not**, then under that select **Strings match**. Put your environment variable as String 1 and leave String 2 empty. Then add your post-build actions below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks to both of you.... was searching it from so much time... !! finally found my fault.